# Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer - Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Been dealing with this error for a while now couldn't get it to gather.

**Error:**
`Error occurred while submitting the review: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer`

**Code:**

````
          const reviewId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
          const newReview = {
            _id: reviewId,
            reviewer: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(interaction.user.id),
            message: message,
            ratingText: ratingText,
          };
          guildData.reviews.push(newReview);
          await guildData.save();
    ```
````

Comment: Assuming you get the error for the line `reviewer: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(interaction.user.id)`, are you sure that `interaction.user.id` is (a) a string of 12 bytes or (b) a string of 24 hex characters or (c) an integer ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the user id of a discord account, which is a string, is not a valid MongoDB Object ID.

The way I would recommend to solve this is:

- If you have a Collection of reviewers/users you would find the reviewer from the reviewers/users collection and put the _id from that into reviewer property.
- If you do not want to store reviewer/user data you can simply make it a string property and set the property just to the user's discord id.

(https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/main/User:Class#id)

Comment: Just a note that in MongoDB, you use ObjectID's for relations between Documents, not as a way of encoding an id.